# Is py-thesaurus still available to use?

Tags: python, nlp, python-import

I have Successfully installed `py-thesaurus-1.0.5`
but...
when I tried using it, It shows nothing...

```
from py_thesaurus import Thesaurus

input_word = "cheap"

new_instance = Thesaurus(input_word)

# Get the synonyms according to part of speech
# Default part of speech is noun

print(new_instance.get_synonym())
print(new_instance.get_synonym(pos='verb'))
print(new_instance.get_synonym(pos='adj'))

# Get the definitions
print(new_instance.get_definition())

# Get the antonyms
print(new_instance.get_antonym())
```

Output is:

```
[] [] [] Give a non-empty argument [] []
```

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

As you can read [here](https://pypi.org/project/py-thesaurus/), this library is no longer maintained.

At the core, *py-thesaurus* was a scraper and crawled various web sites for thesaurus. These sites became more and more difficult to crawl, so the authors stopped py-thesaurus development.

I tried to use this library, but it is not working.